# Don't know which iterative method to use for specific x = f(x)

Tags: numerical-methods

I have this equation 
$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {a_k  x^k} + b*sin(nx) $$
for given $b,a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ ($n$ being dependant on haw many $a_k$ are there) and I have to solve $x=f(x)$ using an iterative method. The only problem I have is I don't know what method should I use. If someone could just give me the name of some method I could use here I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a range in which the solution needs to lie?

Comment: No range unfortunately, that's the whole task.

Comment: @Dario Well, solving $f(x)=x$ screams for the fixed point method. If $f$ will have the good properties to guarantee convergence, that is another matter...